# May be graph theory. Cities connected by airlines

Tags: graph-theory

> There are 175 cities and two airline companies in a certain country. By airlines of each airline company you can get from any city to any other city. The cost of a direct flight between two cities is $2\$$ if they are connected by a single direct airline and $1\$$ if they are connected by two direct airlines.
>
> You want to get from city A to city B and you chose route with the lowest price.
>
> What is the largest amount you may need for this trip?

I think the answer is $232=4+4(175-4)/3$ but I don't know how to prove it.In the example below the  highest price is 4\$ between $A$ and $D$.

[[image: In the example below the highest price between <span class=]$A$ and $D$, green lines represent airlines of company 1 and red lines represent airlines of company 2" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/167uA.png)

Let cities are $A_1,A_2,...,A_{175}$ for any pair $A_iA_j$ let $min_{ij}$ be the lowest price between $A_i and A_j$, we are looking for configuration when $Max{min_{ij}$ is as large as possible.

Comment: What makes you think that that is the answer - Is it because you have found an arrangement with that total cost and are looking to prove that it is maximal? And do you have to pick the cheapest route in the network, or can you pick more expensive ones?

Comment: Are we looking for the airline route arrangement that lets us construct the most expensive possible ticket, or are we looking for the arrangement where the cheapest ticket price to get to the expensivest city is as expensive as possible?

Comment: For given two cities A and B we chose the lowest price between them, but how high this price can be fore some pair of cities?